# Android 4.2+ Activity.OnCreate Fragment

Tags: android, exception

Google play developer console shows this error many times, but I cant't reproduce it at all. Futhermore, I can't understand, what I'm doing wrong.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2340)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2390)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4072)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1270)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5413)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:970)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:786)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:601)
  at android.app.FragmentState.instantiate (Fragment.java:98)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState (FragmentManager.java:1759)
  at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:905)
  at ru.ytaxi40reg.taxi.RegistrationActivity.onCreate (RegistrationActivity.java:58)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5258)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1099)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2280)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: 
  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl (Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:1208)
  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:590)
```

Yes, I see that Android cannott instantiate frament. But my app doesn't use any fragments at all!

Can you explain me where I'm wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: This is line 58 from RegistrationActivity.java

```
...
56  @Override
57  public void onCreate(Bundle p1) {
58      super.onCreate(p1);
59      setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
60      // Other stuff
...
```

**Edit 2**: all file on [gist.gitub.com](https://gist.github.com/iillyyaa2033/a9e1da23243b8858e158f72f4cb9e42c)

Comment: What's going on here: `ru.ytaxi40reg.taxi.RegistrationActivity.onCreate (RegistrationActivity.java:58)`? Can you post your RegActvity class?

Comment: Please place your code for this activity RegistrationActivity.java and line 58

Comment: @AbuQauod here it is.

Comment: Provide your full `RegistrationActivity.java` code please @iillyyaa2033

Comment: @AdityaSonel here it is

Comment: I dont know what is this case exactly, but it could be one of two issues, 1- you have to reduce the images size in your layout.
2- make sure that you are calling your activity in a healthy way. P.S. i recommend to extend your activities from appcompatactivity instead of activity.

Comment: 1. In this layout, I have no images at all. 2. What do you mean - 'a healthy way'?. 3. Use external libraries instead built-in functionality? It looks strange, but I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like system can put incorrect `Bundle savedInstanceState` as argument of `Activity.OnCreate()` method on some android devices.

My workaround is to replace the start of Activity's `onCreate()` method with following lines:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle p1) {

    try{
        super.onCreate(p1);
    }catch(android.app.Fragment.InstantiationException e){
        super.onCreate(null);

    ...
}
```